# Ubuntu 14.04LTS Icons and Theme not working

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, themes, icons

Recently I've installed Ubuntu 14.04, works perfectly, but I tried to change the icons (Numix Circle) and theme (Numix, gtk I guess) with Unity Tweak tool. None of the installed themes or icons are working/changing. When I run `compiz --replace` in terminal, it brings all the changes I've made with the unity tweak tool and everything works perfectly, but on reboot theme and icons resets to default.

After rebooting:

[image: After Rebooting]

After running `compiz --replace`:

[image: After Running compiz --replace]

Answer (score 1):

You could just run it at start up every time (clunky solution i know).

Search for 'Startup Applications', click add, place the command with a title and description. 
It will auto run after startup.